# Integral $\int_0^1\sqrt[2\,n\,]{\frac x{1-x}}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I'm trying to express this integral
$$
\int_0^1\sqrt[2\,n\,]{\frac x{1-x}}\,\mathrm dx
$$

for any $n\in\mathbb N$. I've tried integral by substitution and partial fraction decomposition but it does not seem to lead to the solution.

Do you have any advice ?

My point is to calculate this integral:
[image]

For this I divided it in two integrals:

[image]

I used the substitution method twice. Is the result right now ?
Was there an easier way to express this integral ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what is known as a [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).  Generally:

$$\int_0^1 dx \, x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1} = \frac{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)} $$

In your case,

$$a=1+\frac1{2 n}$$
$$b = 1-\frac1{2 n} $$

So the result is

$$\Gamma \left ( 1+\frac1{2 n} \right ) \Gamma \left ( 1-\frac1{2 n} \right ) $$

which may be simplified to

$$-\frac1{2 n} \Gamma \left ( 1+\frac1{2 n} \right ) \Gamma \left ( -\frac1{2 n} \right ) = \frac{\pi}{2 n \sin{\frac{\pi}{2 n}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method arises by substituting $y=x/(1-x)$; then the integral becomes

$$\int_0^{\infty} dy \, \frac{y^{1/(2 n)} }{(1+y)^2} $$

This may be evaluated by contour integration using the residue theorem.  Consider the contour integral

$$\oint_C dz \, \frac{z^{1/(2 n)} }{(1+z)^2} $$

where $C$ is a keyhole contour about the positive real axis.  The contour integral may be shown to be equal to

$$\left (1-e^{i \pi/n}\right ) \int_0^{\infty} dx \, \frac{x^{1/(2 n)} }{(1+x)^2} $$

By the residue theorem, the contour integral is also equal to

$$-i 2 \pi \frac1{2 n} e^{i \pi/(2 n)} $$

The integral is thus equal to

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, \frac{x^{1/(2 n)} }{(1+x)^2} = \frac{\pi}{2 n \sin{\frac{\pi}{2 n}}} $$

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't know neither about the beta function nor about the residue theorem, I'll try to remerber it for next time.

Answer (score 0):

My point was to calculate this integral:
[image]

For this I divided it in two integrals:

[image]

I used the substitution method twice. Is the result right now ?
Was there an easier way to express this integral ?

[I don't know if it's the right place to ask an other question... I'm sorry if it's not]

Comment: Yes, ask another question.  Better yet, search the site.